# If there are more than x number of pipes in a csv line, then delete the 2nd instance

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a csv file which is supposed to contain 4 columns of data which include a product number, a title, a url and a price. Each column is separated by a `|` delimiter (this has to be maintained, there are other reasons why I can't switch to an alternative delimiter which I won't go into here). As can be seen in the bottom entry (which is the problem entry in this example) the title contains a pipe, which breaks the pattern, which could potentially causes issues if the data needs to be imported into a database.

```
5456435121|The making of the blue album|https://www.example1.co.uk|55
1321354567|Wow this example has no imagination|https://www.cherrypickers.co.uk|89
5456456456|King of the Barbarians | Last Man Standing|https://www.babarians.co.uk|79
```

What I would like to know is, how can I run a command which could effectively analyse the file, and for every line where there are more than 3 pipes( i.e. every line where the title contains a pipe) then delete the 2nd one in that line. This would effectively allow me to remove the pipe(s) in the title if there is one or more present. I don't know how to achieve it.

I would like the file to look like this once processed:

```
5456435121|The making of the blue album|https://www.example1.co.uk|55
1321354567|Wow this example has no imagination|https://www.cherrypickers.co.uk|89
5456456456|King of the Barbarians Last Man Standing|https://www.babarians.co.uk|79
```

Comment: please show sample output

Comment: updated with output data.

Comment: FYI, you can get a list of lines with more than 4 fields with `awk -F'|' 'NF > 4' filename.csv`.  you can use this list to help you correct all such errors.

Comment: and BTW, sophisticated parsers for CSV files (actually, DSV since you're not using a comma) can cope with embedded delimiters by requiring double-quotes around either all fields or just those fields which have the delimiter in the field data.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r ':;s/(\|.*)\|(.*\|.*\|)/\1\2/;t'
```

Deletes every pipe that is preceeded by one and followed by two pipes.

If you want to edit the file in place use `-i` option.

Comment: Nice one this has worked- better than I expected actually. I tried also putting 2 pipes into the title to see how it dealt with that and it also worked as I would have hoped. Thanks man.